# Spring boot app will not fail fast when custom transaction manager fails to connect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp, fail-fast

I am making a spring boot app with a custom transactionManager with its own datasource like so. Btw I'm using hikariCP as the datasource

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRespositories(
basePackages = "..."
entityManagerFactoryRef = "..."
transactionManagerRef = "..."
)
public class myDataSourceConfigration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Configuration("myconfig.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties myconfigDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Configuration("myconfig.datasource.configurations")
    public DataSource myconfigDataSource(){
        return myconfigDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource.class).build;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myconfigEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){
        return builder                
                 .dataSource(myconfigDataSource)
                 .packages(MyClass.class)
                 .build;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager myconfigTransactionManager(
             final @Qualifier ("myconfigEntityManagerFactory")LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean myconfigEntityManagerFactory){
        return new JpaTransactionManager(myconfigEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
}
```

In my application.properties, I have these configurations

```
myconfig.datasource.url:url
myconfig.datasource.username:username
myconfig.datasource.password:password
myconfig.datasource.driverClassName:driverClass
```

Now this all works when its fine but the issue is when it doesn't work. For example, if I put the wrong password, hikari throws a connection pool exception but the app keeps running. I want the app to fail, throw an exception and shutdown but I am having trouble figuring that out. I tried adding another configuration called initializationFailTimeout like so `myConfig.datasource.initializationFailTimeout:5000` but same issue, I see an exception but the app keeps running.

Anyway on how to make spring boot fail fast when hikari throws a connection exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix it by initializing `HikariConfig` bean first and then pass it into `HikariDataSource` constructor:

```
@Bean("myDatasourceHikariConfig")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
    return new HikariConfig();
}

@Bean("myDatasource")
public DataSource myDataSource(@Qualifier("myDatasourceHikariConfig") HikariConfig hikariConfig) {
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}
```

The corresponding part of `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url: jdbc-url
spring.datasource.username: username
spring.datasource.password: WRONG
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: driver
spring.datasource.type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

#Following are hikari specific properties
spring.datasource.initializationFailTimeout: 5000
spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size: 10
spring.datasource.minimum-idle: 1
spring.datasource.connection-timeout: 30000
spring.datasource.pool-name: datasource-pool
```

Note that all these properties are just with prefix `spring.datasource` (I don't use `spring.datasource.hikari` from `DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class`).

Using `DataSourceBuilder` for initializing datasource leads to exactly the same behavior as you described (the app throws an exception about the wrong password but continue to launch nevertheless). I confirm that it stops launching only when you don't have custom transaction manager etc.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.9 with HikariCP 3.2.0.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I had no idea it was the way I was constructing my datasource beans. Going to update my question to include these